# System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException - Excel can't access file (...)

Tags: vb.net, runtime-error, excel-interop

I've googled everything. Still no idea what's happening.

I have a vb.net form that let's me insert txt file values into excel.
The thing is it gives me an error when i use
`xlWorkSheet.SaveAs("C:\" & TextBox3.Text & ".xlsx")`

but when i use `xlWorkSheet.SaveAs("C:\Users\User\Desktop\" & TextBox3.Text & ".xlsx")` it works fine ( in my computer ). In other computers it gives me the same error..

The error is System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException , and the "extension" depends almost everytime.
Microsoft Excel can't access the file 'C:\C6703D00'. ( i refer to C6703D00 nowhere)

[kinda translating]- Error details:

• Filename or path don't exist

• the file is already in use.

• the workbook you're trying to save has the same name as an open book.

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 vb.net .netframework v4.5 ..
i can post more code in question if you need.

Comment: You cannot store files in the C:\ directory.  Excel probably tries to do something about it, like redirecting to isolated storage and that did not pan out well.  Pick a better directory, use Environment.GetFolderPath() or SaveFileDialog

Comment: but when i save in C:\Users\User\Desktop\ , after installing the program in a different computer, i have the same error. anyway i'll give it a try ! brb

Comment: it worked fine like this ! thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When code works on your computer and not another computer at the point of the SaveAs then you should validate that the path exists e.g. where .... is a TODO for your path

```
If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TextBox3.Text) Then
    Dim fileName As String = IO.Path.Combine("C:\....", TextBox3.Text)
    Dim folder As String = IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName)
    If IO.Directory.Exists(folder) Then
        ' save
    Else
        ' path not found
    End If
End If
```

Other issues could not the user does not have access to the folder.

Comment: thank you! but im gonna use the Environment.GetFolderPath() ! it worked just fine like this.